# Newly upgraded Visual Studio 2010 runs much slower than 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Is Visual studio 2010 slower than 2005? I just had my laptop upgraded to windows 7 64bit with visual studio 2010, and vs 2010 is much slower than vs2005 was when I had xp. Any upgrades or configurations you can think of that might help me out?

Comment: Each new major release of VS has always been slower than its predecessor. 2008 is also slower than 2005.

Comment: @Matt Oh those VS 6.0 days...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off the "Enable rich client visual experience" and turn on "Use graphics hardware acceleration if available"

Comment: This seemed to help quite a bit. I also temporarily disabled my antivirus software which made a load of difference.

Answer (score 2):

Extra features always come at a cost. If you don't upgrade your computer at a similar rate you upgrade your software, you'll find it gets slower and slower.

About VS2010 specifically, the UI uses WPF, so you need at least a decently passable graphics card to handle it. Intellisense also got a lot better, so it will use slightly more CPU.

For what it's worth, 2010 runs very smoothly on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your setup, Visual Studio 2010 can be faster than VS 2010 or slower. I'm not sure from your question in what way Visual Studio is running slower, though.
Is it just Visual Studio, or is anything else slower?

- You mentioned you're running Windows 7 x64. If you have more than 4 GB of RAM, this is a good idea. If you have less than 4 GB, you're probably going to be slower than if you're running 32-bit. It's also worth looking at your Windows 7 performance rating--if it's low, applications like Visual Studio will be slow too.
- The hardware requirements are listed over at http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate/system-requirements, but those are bare-bones requirements. If you're doing SharePoint development, then you'll need a much beefier system (SharePoint will compete for a lot of your system resources). I'd want at least 1 GB more RAM than recommended there even without SharePoint. The processor speed is fine for multiple cores, but if you have an old laptop 1.6 GHz and a single core won't be that fast.
- Most people find an SSD drive helps incredibly.
- Launching Visual Studio does seem to take longer, but to me it runs faster once it's up. F1 help is non-blocking now. Compiles can be done in parallel. Navigation and adding references is faster.
- Grab the productivity power pack from vscodegallery.com--that adds a lot of shortcuts.
- Visual Studio has more features than previous versions. Most people install everything. It may be better to just install the features you need.
- The previous poster mentioned having a good video card or chipset. That's probably a good idea, but disk I/O and CPU are probably more important.